# No sound when monitor turned off in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on a Revo r3610 nettop with integrated sound and graphics.

When I boot up with the monitor turned on everything works fine. If I then turn off the monitor sound continues to work as normal. However if I boot up with the monitor turned off, I cannot play sound. When I turn on the monitor, it just suspends itself without displaying a picture. If I VNC to the box, the sound icon in the tray shows as muted (three dashes) and nothing is shown in the hardware sound devices panel. The sound card does still show up in an `lspci` listing though.

The monitor is connected via HDMI and the sound is via 3.5mm headphone jack to an external amp. The monitor also has integrated speakers but these are not in use.

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thanks. I get confused by the number of different StackExchanges with overlapping subject areas!